# Aligning margin note with line spacing different from main text

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, marginpar

I have a main text column with margin a line separation of 1.05 (`\setstretch{1.05}`), and margin texts generated with a tighter line separation with the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\mnote}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedright\textsf{\footnotesize{%
\textsf{\footnotesize{%
\begin{spacing}{1.025}%
#1%
\end{spacing}%
}}}}}}%
```

This results in the following output, where the margin paragraph is not properly algined with the first line of the paragraph of the adjacent main text:

[misaligned margin note http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19252957/mnote.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19252957/mnote.png)

This is kind of a tough problem to solve. Does someone have any suggestions?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want the output to be. The baseline of the marginpar text should align with the baseline of the line of the main text?

Comment: Beside David’s observation you could also take a look at package `marginnote`, which places margin notes on the current line. The macro `\marginnote` provides an optional argument for the vertical adjustment (and the package itself has options regarding this).

Comment: Yes, the baseline of the marginpar text should be aligned with the baseline of the main text line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the `spacing` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\mnote}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedright
\textsf{\footnotesize{%
\begin{spacing}{1.025}%
#1%
\end{spacing}%
}}}}

\newcommand{\mnoteb}[1]{{\marginpar{\raggedright\sffamily\footnotesize
\setstretch{1.025}%
#1}}}

\def\a{One two three four five. }

\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.5}

\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\mnote{\a\a}
\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\mnoteb{\a\a}
\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a
\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a

\end{document}
```