# Change linespacing within marginnote

Tags: line-spacing, marginnote

I am trying to change the linespacing within a marginnote such that it is different from the main document. I have tried all approaches described in [Temporarily increase line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48741/temporarily-increase-line-spacing) and [Aligning margin note with line spacing different from main text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56123/aligning-margin-note-with-line-spacing-different-from-main-text), but none of them worked. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.25}

\renewcommand{\a}{One Two Three Four Five }

\newcommand{\newdef}[2][0]{\marginnote{{\setstretch{0.8}\emph{#2}}}[#1\baselineskip]}

\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\newdef{spanning multiple lines}
\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using

```
\newcommand{\newdef}[2][0]{\marginnote{{\setstretch{0.6}\emph{#2}\endgraf}}[#1\baselineskip]}

\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\newdef{spanning multiple lines; in this case even more than tree}
\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a
```

I get
[image]

Comment: the image in your edit (for which you show no source) is expected behaviour if you specify a baselineskip that is not large enough to fit in the letters, note the descender on the `p`. Why do you want to reduce baselineskip so much without reducing the font size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete a spurious `{}` group that is reverting the change before the end of the note:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.25}

\renewcommand{\a}{One Two Three Four Five }

\newcommand{\newdef}[2][0]{\marginnote{\setstretch{0.8}\emph{#2}}[#1\baselineskip]}

\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\newdef{spanning multiple lines}
\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help. The result is the same as in my updated question.

Comment: @Florian in the original question the linespacing did not change and you asked how to change it for example by 0.8. this answers that exactly. If that is not what you want edit your question to state in words what you do want.

Comment: The problem is not about the linespacing value in itself, but about the fact that starting from the third line the linespacing seems not to be respected. I can understand that this was not clear.

Comment: @Florian then make an example that has three lines, and ask about that (whatever that issue is it is unrelated to the original problem where the linespacing was not changed at all)

Comment: @Florian if you set text of the same size on a baseline reduced to 80% then there is no room for the larger letters so even spacing is impossible, that is unrelated to `\marginpar`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If you change the `spanning multiple lines` for a longer text like `\a\a`, one can notice that the first lineskip is larger than the rest following it. This seems to be a `\marginnote` related issue, since in your [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56123/aligning-margin-note-with-line-spacing-different-from-main-text) it does not happen with `\marginpar`. Any ideas how to force the first lineskip to match the others?

Answer (score 2):

Here I put it in a `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.25}

\renewcommand{\a}{One Two Three Four Five }

\newcommand{\newdef}[1]{\marginnote{\setstretch{.6}\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\emph{#1}}}}

\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a on this line\newdef{spanning multiple lines we can try this}
\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is weird. While this solution seems to work for three lines, it does not work for four: http://i.imgur.com/Qm87gyC.png

Comment: @Florian the number of lines is unrelated to your problem, it is just the position of ascenders and descenders in the text that you use.

Comment: I see, thank you. I was not aware that there is an interdependence between the linespacing and the font size. At least I would have expected that the lines 'overlay' equally.

Comment: @Florian If you reduce the baselineskip by 0.8 you are specifying a 10pt font on a 9.6pt baseline, Tex can no maintain an even spacing given such a requirement.

Comment: @Florian but the MWE you originally posted did not have this problem at all as the spurious `{}` group meant that the baselineskip did not change at all.

Comment: The `\pbox` solves the spacing problem, but I get a lot of underfull box warnings in my real document where I have dozens of marginnotes. Any quick ideas how to fix them?

Comment: @Mappi Use `\raggedright`, as in `\newcommand{\newdef}[1]{\marginnote{\setstretch{.6}\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright\emph{#1}}}}
`

Comment: @Mappi If you don't like the look of `\raggedright`, you could replace it with `\sloppy`, though that might still have underfull boxes.